# Test sound works but no audio speaker output

Tags: audio, drivers, speakers

Sys: Dell Studio XPS 8100, MB: OT568R/DH57M01 BIOS: A05,Legacy
CPU: Intel i7 860 Mem:8gb, DDR3 GPU:AMD Radeon 6770
OS:  Win10 10.0.19042

Audio I/O driver:     MS 10.0.19041.1 12/06/19,
Realtek audio driver: 6.0.1.6299 01/25/11(orig OEM spec, installed in Device Mgr>Sound Controller),
Ext Speakers:         Logitech X540(6)

Issue: HDMI audio works fine but audio from ext Logitech speakers does not. Sound test works but nothing
from other sources. Tried the above Realtek orig driver as well as R273 & R282. Question: What is the
difference between the driver installed under "Audio Inputs & Outputs" and the Realtek driver installed under "Sound Controller", could this be the issue? Any help or assistance much appreciated!!

Comment: are the speakers plugged into the 3.5 jack that have the problem? and do you still have the HDMI connected?

Comment: yes, connected to rca ports in rear. yes hdmi is still connected but realtek driver is selected which terminates the hdmi connection. Had these speakers working long time ago but wondering if it was prior to Win10 install.